# data from a std::vector reference becomes corrupt after return from function call

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I have a `std::vector< tr1::shared_ptr<mapObject> >` that I'm trying build from data contained in a compressed file.  Here's the function I'm attempting to do that with:

```
    using std::tr1::shared_ptr;

    template<typename T>
    void loadSharedPtrVector(std::vector< shared_ptr<T> >& vect, TCODZip& zip)
    // the TCODZip is the compression buffer I'm loading the data from.  It's
    // working correctly and isn't really part of this problem.
    {
        vect.clear();

        // load the size of the saved vector
        int numT = zip.getInt();

        // load the saved vector            
        for(int i=0; i<numT; ++i)
        {
            int type = zip.getInt();
            shared_ptr<T> Tptr(new T);
            T newT = T::loadType(type, zip);                
            Tptr.reset(&newT);
            std::cerr << "load: " << Tptr->getPosition() << std::endl; // outputs correct values
            vect.push_back(Tptr);
        }
        for(int i=0; i<numT; ++i)
        {
            // outputs the last value pushed onto vect
            std::cerr << "loadDone: " << vect[i]->getPosition() << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

The above function is called by this bit of code here:

```
        typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr<mapObject> featurePtr;

        // 'features' is a std::vector<featurePtr>, 'zip' is a TCODZip previously declared
        utility::loadSharedPtrVector<mapObject>(features, zip);

        vector<featurePtr>::const_iterator fit;
        for(fit=features.begin(); fit<features.end(); ++fit) 
        {
            // outputs mostly garbage
            cerr << "afterCall: " << (*fit)->getPosition() << endl;
        }
```

When this is run, the `cerr` statements give this output (each set of output has ~50 lines, so I cut out most for brevity):

```
load: (5,40)
load: (5,45)
load: (5,58)
(etc.  all 'load' lines are correct output)
load: (87,68)
load: (11,5)
loadDone: (11,5)
loadDone: (11,5)
loadDone: (11,5)
loadDone: (11,5)
loadDone: (11,5)
loadDone: (11,5)
(etc. all 'loadDone' lines are the same)
afterCall: (11,5)
afterCall: (10,1)
afterCall: (10,1)
afterCall: (10,1)
afterCall: (10,1)
afterCall: (10,1)
afterCall: (10,1)
(etc. all 'afterCall' lines are the same except for the first)
```

I apparently have some misconceptions about how shared_ptrs work.  I realized that I'm pushing copies of `Tptr` into `vect`, and that's why all of its indices are the same, although I thought that declaring a new shared_ptr in the loop would make a separate pointer from the other ones already in `vect`, but I guess not.

I have no idea why the 'afterCall' set of output is different from the 'loadDone' set (except for that first value). In addition to `(10,1)` it has also output `(2274756,134747232)` and `(134747232, 16)`, although it outputs `(10,1)` more than any other.

I suspect that my problem boils down to my misuse of `shared_ptr`.  Can anyone tell me exactly how I'm misusing it?  The tutorials I find online haven't been very helpful in this regard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
     T newT = T::loadType(type, zip);
     Tptr.reset(&newT);
```

You give `shared_ptr` pointer to stack memory, which is reclaimed at function return and is no longer valid. Allocate that from the heap:

```
shared_ptr<T> Tptr( new T( T::loadType( type, zip )));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have spotted the same defect in your code as Nikolai did, and erased the shared_ptr which is useless:

```
template<typename T>
void loadSharedPtrVector(std::vector<T> & vect, TCODZip& zip)
// the TCODZip is the compression buffer I'm loading the data from.  It's
// working correctly and isn't really part of this problem.
{
    vect.clear();

    // load the size of the saved vector
    int numT = zip.getInt();

    // load the saved vector            
    for(int i=0; i<numT; ++i)
    {
        int type = zip.getInt();
        vect.push_back(T::loadType(type, zip));
    }
    for(int i=0; i<numT; ++i)
    {
        // outputs the last value pushed onto vect
        std::cerr << "loadDone: " << vect[i].getPosition() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Without knowing something about the `mapObject` class, we can't say that the shared_ptr is useless.  Maybe `mapObject` has no copy constructor, or maybe the copy constructor has poor performance.

Comment: `mapObject` is an abstract base class, and `features` is a vector containing objects derived from it.  Since I can't instantiate `mapObject` directly, I need to have a pointer to it.